# Things that work with xampp are not working with Apache Tomcat, why?

Tags: xampp

I have created a form with form validation with PHP.

The Form is working perfectly with xampp server, but its not working with Tomcat.

Why???

xampp- working perfectly:

[image]

Tomcat - not working:

[image]